# Get size of HTML5 WebDB (Web SQL) database from javascript

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, html, web-sql

I'm using the WebDB spec in HTML5 to create an offline database for persistent offline storage. However, I need a way to get the current size of the database from javascript.

The only thing I can think of is to loop through everything in the database, and add the size of all the objects. The only problem is this only works for primitive values, so this would only work if I first serialized all of my javascript objects (using JSON), and seems like a hack.

Is there any better way of doing it? I need accurate numbers.

Thanks for any help

Comment: 'pragma page_count' * 'pragma page_size' would work except its not allowed by most (all?) implementations (such as webkit)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I could do with this too

Comment: Nope. Doesn't appear that there's any way to do it unless the two pragma commands I listed above make it into the webDB spec

Comment: The SQL database was booted out of HTML5 long ago and work on the SQL database has stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Painful solution but what I'm doing is using a size counter in local storage for each table in the DB and wrapping insert, select, update, drop etc. I don't think this will account for sqlite history, but it should provide some way to constrain growth or drop older data as needed.